# Martingale: Proof of strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes, martingales, law-of-large-numbers

Is there any book or article that give a formal proof of strong law of large numbers by using martingale?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you might try the book by David Williams called something like "probability with martingales"

Comment: "Measures, integrals and martingales" by Rene Schilling (Example 24.8 in the 2nd edition). If you speak german, then you can also take a look at "Martingale und Prozesse" by the same author.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on martingale convergence theorems cites this article: The https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec11Add.pdf, which seems likely to be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This and more is explained in a 1971 expository article by J.L. Doob in the *Mathematical Monthly*: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317751. Unless I am mistaken, the (backwards) martingale proof of the strong law of large numbers is due to Doob, in the 1940s.